# Stopping systemd service with salt-tack

Tags: raspbian, salt-stack

I am using salt-stack to manage my production machine.
The minions run Raspbian and my and I have configured a systemd service. The services config file is located at /lib/systemd/system/my_service.service

When I run the following command:

```
sudo salt my_minion service.stop my_service
```

The following error is returned:

```
ERROR: Unable to run command ['/etc/init.d/my_service', 'stop'] with the context {'with_communicate': True, 'shell': False, 'env': {'LANG': 'en_GB.UTF-8', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'LC_ALL': 'C'}, 'stdout': -1, 'close_fds': True, 'stdin': None, 'stderr': -2, 'cwd': '/root'}, reason: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I understand that salt tries to use sysvinit instead of systemd.

Is there any way to tell salt to use systemd?

**EDIT:**

Tried adding

```
providers:
  service: systemd
```

to /etc/salt/minion as suggested by Eric. Still getting the same error

**EDIT 2**

The issue was fixed by using Erics suggestion + upgrading salt-minion to 2015.8.8 from 2015.8.3

Comment: checking both  salt.states.services , it say "The current status of a service is determined by the return code of the init/rc script status command." . Just use salt modules.cmd  as work around.

Comment: But there is definitely a salt module that deals with systemd services:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.systemd.html
I just don't know how to make salt using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because newer Raspbian is based off of Debian 8, and Salt's systemd execution module does not properly detect newer Raspbian as needing systemd. Can the OP please reply to this message with the output from `sudo salt my_minion grains.items`? Please redact any grains which you feel have personally-identifiable information, I'm mainly interested in the grains that deal with OS name and version.

**EDIT:** One more thing. Please confirm that `/run/systemd/system` exists on the Raspbian box. What I think is happening here is two modules are both claiming to be the ones to provide the `service` module.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/32421 should fix this, but you can work around this immediately (without waiting for a new Salt release) by adding the following  to `/etc/salt/minion` on your Raspbian minions:

```
providers:
  service: systemd
```

Comment: Also, the reply in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36479715/1200367 is wrong. Please disregard it.

Comment: I just delete my reply.  XD

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried to do as you suggested, still getting the same error (more details in the question)